# Using form multiple times in same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am new to full stack development. I am trying to write a text based game where you get input (north, south, east, west) from the user, use that input to access the mySQL database to get the new location, and update the text on the page accordingly. They should be able to enter input until they enter the room with the villain or until they have collected all the items (1 per room). The issue I am currently running into the issue that nothing happens with the user input. At one point, it would accept input and display a message but would not accept further input in the same form. I have very little experience in HTML and CSS, and none in JavaScript or PHP. I know the code is sloppy but right now I'm just trying to figure out how to get the input to work properly. I'm not sure if I should be using ajax to update the page in real time or just use jQuery. Should some of the info I am using PHP for be done in JavaScript?
I have tried using ajax but it doesn't seem the input is being communicated now. At one point it was sending the data but it would only accept input once. I'm completely lost and overwhelmed with how much information is out there. If someone could at least point me in the right direction on what to search for, I'd appreciate it.

**Edited to include prepared statements. My input box now takes one input and does what it's supposed to. But it won't register if I type the same input in again (i.e. to go north twice), and if I type anything else, $_POST is empty.

TL;DR: Using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, MySQL to get and handle input on the same page multiple times.
Game.php Class (in case accessing db is my issue):

```php
public function getDirections($conn) {
    $check = "SELECT direction FROM " . $this->currTable;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($check);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result)) {
        if ($result - > num_rows) {
            while ($row = $result - > fetch_assoc()) {
            echo " [" . $row["direction"] . "]";
      }
    }
  }
}

public function getNextRoom($conn, $direction) {
    $check = "SELECT destination, newtable FROM " . $this->currTable . " WHERE direction=?;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($check);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $direction);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();  
    if ($result) {
        if ($result - > num_rows) {
            while ($row = $result - > fetch_assoc()) {
            $this - > currRoom = $row["destination"];
            $this - > currTable = $row["newtable"];
            }
        }
    } else {
    echo "That's not a valid direction. Try again.";
  }
  $this - > printStatement($conn);
}

public function getItem() {
  if ($this - > currRoom != 'the parking lot') {
    $result = array_search($this - > currRoom, $this - > items);
    if ($result == 'Toby') {
      echo $this - > fail;
    }
    elseif (!in_array($result, $this - > inventory)) {
      array_push($this - > inventory, $result);
    }
  }
  echo implode($this - > inventory);
}

public function printStatement($conn) {
  $this - > getItem();
  echo "<br> You are in $this->currRoom.";
  echo "<br> Which direction would you like to go?";
  $this - > getDirections($conn);
}
```

dwight.php (inside body):

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

<div id="main">
    <form action="dwight.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="inputDirection" placeholder="Where to?">
        <input type="button" value="Let's Go!">
    </form>
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST["inputDirection"])){
        $direction = $_POST["inputDirection"];
        $dwight->getNextRoom($conn, $direction);
    }
    else{
        echo "You are in the parking lot. <br> Which direction would you like to go? [north]";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: image of code is not code...

Comment: Your code also is open to SQL injections which could be your issue. Use prepared statements and parameterize query. Also, it is not a `jquery` or `ajax` question, ajax can run inside of jquery or in native js.

Comment: The last code block I posted is where I'm passing it. ```if (isset($_GET['direction'])){$direction = $_GET['direction']}```. I then pass that variable into a function. Am I doing that correctly?

Comment: “I am new to full stack development” - first, welcome! Second, skip AJAX until you get everything else down. It is a great way to enhance something, but you need the basics first and troubleshooting it can be very hard and frustrating if you don’t have a good understanding of what is happening. Also, I’d personally tell you to skip jQuery in favor of pure JS, however there is also a decade or two of tutorials out there of “how to’s” with jQuery as magic glue, and although I think it is not needed anymore, it is still totally valid these days.

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a CSS problem? Also, be warned that your database queries are highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing a # when you specify the `direction`, so

```
var direction = $("direction").val();
```

should be

```
var direction = $("#direction").val();
```

Secondly, you should let the system know the php script name to call . Say for example the PHP script is having the name `testajax1Sept2023.php`, then please use

```
    url: "testajax1Sept2023.php",
```

So, to demonstrate, you may use the following HTML:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="result"></div>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="direction" placeholder="Where to?">
  <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="javascript:testajax();" value="Let's Go!">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function testajax() {
 var direction = $("#direction").val();
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       data: { "direction": direction} ,
       url: "testajax1Sept2023.php",
       success: function(response){
           $("#result").html(response);
         }
   });   
}

</script>
```

and the following sample PHP script (with the name testajax1Sept2023.php):

```
<?php
// testajax.php

echo "You have chosen " . $_GET["direction"]; 

?>
```

You may test running it thru this [sandbox](https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO1Sep2023.html)

After testing it, you will know the basics of using ajax, now you can change your code to link with the MySQL database (please remember to change your queries to parameterized prepared statements which are resilient against SQL injection, as advised by user3783243)

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML : 

<div id="main">
    <form id="gameForm" action="dwight.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="inputDirection" placeholder="Where to?">
        <input type="submit" value="Let's Go!">
    </form>
<!-- Show game details within the form -->
    <?php
    $dwight->printStatement($conn);
    ?>
</div>

Script js:

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Intercept form submission
    $("#gameForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from being submitted the conventional way.

        // Get the form data
        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        // Send an AJAX request to the server
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dwight.php",
            data: formData,
            success: function(response) {
                // Update the page's game details.
                $("#main").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

PHP :

if (!empty($_POST["inputDirection"])) {
    $direction = $_POST["inputDirection"];
    $dwight->getNextRoom($conn, $direction);
} else {
    echo "You are in the parking lot. <br> Which direction would you like to go? [north]";
}
```

You expected to have a more responsive and interactive text-based game after implementing these modifications.